# facet_wrap fill by column

Tags: r, ggplot2

As far as I can tell `facet_wrap` fills by row.  In the same way you can specify how to fill a `matrix` with `byrow` I was hoping you could do the same with facet_wrap.  I know I could reorder the levels of a factor to plot in this maner but this seems like a bit of work if there's a shorter method that I'm overlooking.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear,  y=mpg, fill=vs)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~ carb, ncol=2)  #fills by row
```

How can we fill by column?

Comment: Good question. Post it as a feature request for Winston on the `ggplot2` [repo](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues?labels=feature&page=1&state=open). :)

Comment: Done: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/695

Comment: Though maybe I added the request in the wrong spot as the link doesn't match yours.

Comment: Also, I think this situation is rarely important for folks that one could just use `gridExtra` and `grid.arrange` to achieve the right configuration. At least, that would be a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: I think you did fine. Someone just needs to tag it as a feature (and only repo admins can do that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done by converting faceting variable into factor and then re-leveling it. In function `relevel.byrow` I used `matrix(..., byrow=T)` for level ordering, then converted this matrix into a vector using `c()` function and then re-leveled factor.

```
#number of columns
nc <- 2
level.byrow <- function(vec, nc){
  fac <- factor(vec) #if it is not a factor
  mlev <- matrix(levels(fac), nrow=nc, byrow=T)
  factor(fac, levels= c(mlev))
}

library(plyr)
ggplot(transform(mtcars, rcarb=level.byrow(carb, nc)), aes(x=gear,  y=mpg, fill=vs)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ rcarb, ncol=nc)
```

I used `plyr` for convenience, you can just simply write

```
mtcars$rcarb <- level.byrow(mtcars$carb, nc)
```

This also works when we don't have full facet structure, but gives couple warnings.

```
mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars, carb!=3)
ggplot(transform(mtcars2, rcarb=level.byrow(carb, nc)), aes(x=gear,  y=mpg, fill=vs)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ rcarb, ncol=nc)
```

Result with `carb==3` excluded:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the by column option is not available for facet_wrap.  This solution suffers from a rearrangement of levels and thus a new variable should be created to preserve the original.  Not ideal but I think the best work around right now.  Thank you for your thought.

Answer (score 17):

This feature is implemented in the current development version of ggplot2 on github. [This commit](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/7e36e4f5927982d4a459717f98133f689f59e5d0) implements a new parameter `dir` of `facet_wrap`, so you'd simply do

```
## "v" for vertical or "h" for horizontal (the default)    
ggplot(...) + facet_wrap(~ carb, ncol=2, dir="v")
```

Note that this feature is currently not available in the version on CRAN.

Comment: This is the current ideal solution because of ease of implementation. The `dir` parameter to `facet_wrap()` is now part of the CRAN ggplot2 release.