# How to change from row to column major order with facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a 2x4 array of plots that show distributions changing over time. The default `ggplot` arrangement with `facet_wrap` is that the top row has series 1&2, the second row has series 3&4, etc. I would like to change this so that the first column has series in order (1->2->3->4) and then the second column has the next 4 series. This way your eye can compare immediately adjacent distributions in time vertically (as I think they should be).

Comment: Change the levels of wrapping factor..see [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490638/how-to-change-the-order-of-facet-labels-in-ggplot-custom-facet-wrap-labels)

Comment: I realize I can do this, but when the levels are just time points, it's a little kludgy, don't you think? The levels would be something like (1,10,2,20,3,30,4,40,...) and so on.

Comment: I dont get your point here. can you provide a reproducible example please.

Comment: There's really not much to get. If you use facet_wrap(~time) the order of plots will by default to increase across the rows and then columns. I want to reverse that. AFAICT, the only way seems to be able to re-level time as a factor out-of-order.

Comment: You could make a dummy variable that is a factor in the reverse order of your time variable, and use that in your plot instead... as I type this I see Dwin has already provided this as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facet\_wrap fill by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888302/facet-wrap-fill-by-column)

Answer (score 11):

Use the direction `dir` parameter to `facet_wrap()`. Default is horizontal, and this can be switched to vertical:

```
# Horizontally
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ cyl, ncol=2)

# Vertically
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ cyl, ncol=2, dir="v")
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to do this with the ordering factor prior to the the facet_wrap call:

```
 fac <- factor( fac, levels=as.character(c(1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 40) ) )
```

The default for as/table in `facet_wrap` is TRUE which is going to put the lowest value ("1" in this case) at the upper left and the highest value ("40" in the example above) at the lower right corner. So:

```
 pl + facet_wrap(~fac, ncol=2, nrow=4)
```

Your comments suggest you are working with numeric class variables. (Your comments still do not provide a working example and you seem to think this is our responsibility and not yours. Where does one acquire such notions of entitlement?) This should create a factor that might be "column major" ordered with either numeric of factor input:

```
> ss <- 1:8; factor(ss, levels=ss[matrix(ss, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)])
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Levels: 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8
```

On the other hand I can think of situations where this might be the effective approach:

```
> ss <- 1:8; factor(ss, levels=ss[matrix(ss, nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)])
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Levels: 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is the only way to do it. I just don't like it, because it's not very elegant. Oh, well. Can't win 'em all. Thanks.

Comment: Your work case must be different, since the default ordering of the example I offered is the same as I created. Best answers are always achieved by greatest amount of information in the question.

Comment: All the information that is needed I have given. facet_wrap(~time) where time = 1,2,3,4... This will plot across rows first and then columns by default. Are you saying you get something different than that where it plots down the columns first and then the rows?

Comment: I was thinking it might be interesting to show `unique(fac)`. There are options about whether to display top first or bottom first and then there are the ordering option that arise once we know the specifics of the levels. The "devil is in the details" of what those three dots actually are.

Comment: In this case, I'm selecting rows out of the data set like ggplot(data[(data$days == 1 | data$days == 2 | data$days == 3),]).

Comment: Need a specific example. That one clearly does not fit the case of a 2 x 4 arrangement. The  ...like... approach to problem description just doesn't provide enough of a cognitive "handle". You seem to be expecting us to read your mind and make up an example that will work for you.

Comment: Do you really need me to type this? Just extend up until data$days == 8.

Comment: What I really needed was a working example with the features of the data object.